# Fragment how to enter onCreateView lifecycle method

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to create a new instance of a Fragment in a PagerAdapter with some method like `Fragment1.newInstance(0);`
but this does not enter the Fragment onCreateView method, where I want to take its layout... How can I make it enter the lifecycle method?

EDIT: For the swipe tabs I am using an external library, that extends `PagerAdapter`, maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Creating an instance of a `Fragment` doesn't mean it will become fully functional. It needs to be attached to an `Activity` at which point the OS will initialise it fully and call the various life-cycle methods. You cannot (or more accurately *SHOULD NOT* call `Fragment` life-cycle methods directly).

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). See section "Adding a fragment to an activity" especially to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your pager adapter class return the instance like this

```
 @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position){
 return Fragment1.newInstance(position);
}
```

And in your Fragment create a static instance like this

```
public static NearbyOffersFragment newInstance(int position) {
    Fragment1 f = new Fragment1();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("position", position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}
```

and onCreate of your fragment retrieve the postion

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    position = getArguments().getInt("position");
}
```

Comment: that still does not enter the Fragment's onCreateView method

Comment: are you sure you are logging it and checking??

Comment: Even i used that libary for the tabs and it is working fine with me..Show your code in OnCreateView

Answer (score 0):

This is because ViewPager doesn't recreate fragment on each swipe .. it creates fragment only once and keeps in memory and recreate once after it goes offScreenpageLimit() ...For recreating fragment each time you swipe ,you have to set

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

But this method is not recommended if you have so many pages in viewpager (atleast more than 10)..